# How to serialize Django queryset.values() into json?

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-serializer

I have a model that has many fields, however for this problem I only need 3 of those fields. When I try to serialize a `.values` set I get an exception:

> 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'

This is my code:

```
queryset = myModel.objects.filter(foo_icontains=bar).values('f1', 'f2', 'f3')
serialized_q = serializers.serialize('json', queryset, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: What exception are you receiving?

Comment: `'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'`

Comment: did you try it with `queryset = myModel.objects.filter(foo_icontains=bar).values('foo.f1', 'foo.f2', 'foo.f3')`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a django ValuesQuerySet to a json object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601174/converting-a-django-valuesqueryset-to-a-json-object)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Django serializers can only serialize queryset, [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) does not return queryset rather `ValuesQuerySet` object. So, avoid using `values()`. Rather, specifiy the fields you wish to use in `values()`, in the serialize method as follows:

Look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601174/converting-a-django-valuesqueryset-to-a-json-object/6601250#6601250) for example

```
objectQuerySet = ConventionCard.objects.filter(ownerUser = user)
data = serializers.serialize('json', list(objectQuerySet), fields=('fileName','id'))
```

Instead of using `objectQuerySet.values('fileName','id')`, specify those fields using the `fields` parameter of `serializers.serialize()` as shown above.

Comment: Yes I am aware that `.values()` returns a list, however simplejson.dumps gives me a `jsondata is not JSON serializable`, the `ValuesQuerySet` is in the form: `[{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}]`

Comment: Yes, it depends on what data looks like, the first example from the linked answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: @bash- just call `list()` on it first.

Comment: Yes `list(ValuesQuerySet)` should return list which can then be serialized with `simplejson`.

Comment: thanks, just a side note, in the SO question you linked, does that approach query the db for all the fields and then subset it for the 2 fields or would it only query the db for just those 2 fields?

Comment: I think it would query all fields, you could perhaps use [`only`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only) when querying. Though I am not quite sure. [Debug it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748295/getting-the-sql-from-a-django-queryset) to see how the query looks like.

Comment: Remember that will only work if you get one result. `list()` solution will work in both cases.

Comment: @rebus thanks, it didn't work before because there was a DecimalField and it couldn't be serialized

Answer (score 59):

As other people have said, Django's [serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/serialization/) can't handle a ValuesQuerySet.  However, you can serialize by using a standard `json.dumps()` and transforming your ValuesQuerySet to a list by using `list()`.  If your set includes Django fields such as Decimals, you will need to pass in [DjangoJSONEncoder](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/serializers/json.py#L88).  Thus:

```
import json
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

queryset = myModel.objects.filter(foo_icontains=bar).values('f1', 'f2', 'f3')
serialized_q = json.dumps(list(queryset), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

Comment: Finally, this helped me which I want the Queryset to be converted to JSON and then returned to the template.

Comment: @Kyle_397 . not sure you need this for sending queryset to your template. I think Django is able to handle a raw queryset. On the other hand, eg. Celery (or its broker in my case) is not

Answer (score 25):

Make list from objectQuerySet:

```
data_ready_for_json = list( ConventionCard.objects.filter(ownerUser = user).values('fileName','id') )
```

Comment: This was the quickest and simplest solution for me. I appended `JsonResponse(data_ready_for_json, safe=False)` and it worked perfectly in an Ajax call.

Comment: I had similar problem. Above solution of using list(queryset) worked very well. Thanks Max!

Comment: This works like a charm!!!

Comment: Also, you have the chance to manipulate the list before returning it, which might be very convenient

Answer (score 6):

My solution, It's work fine

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
import json

permission_list = Permission.objects.all().order_by('-id')
permission_serialize= json.loads(serialize('json', permission_list))
return JsonResponse({'data': permission_serialize})
```

Comment: Why do you `serialize()` and then `loads()` just to have the `JsonResponse` serialize the list again. This is extra, unnecessary work.

Answer (score 3):

Just cast to dict every item and create json with json.dumps:

```
json.dumps([dict(item) for item in SomeModel.objects.all().values('id', 'title')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
queryset = myModel.objects.filter(foo_icontains=bar)
serialized_q = serializers.serialize(queryset, many = True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).