# write nested data in JSON file from Django database

Tags: python, json, django, python-2.7, sqlite

I want to avail a feature with which data can be fetched from database(sqlite3) and downloaded as a .json file. the data present in database are emails which has fields like to,from etc. I am facing problem in fetching and then writing it to .json. the data i am getting is an object which is giving this **error** while writing to .json `"<UserData: UserData object> is not JSON serializable"` . Below I have give few code snippets, please do help..

---

If data can be fetched in this format then work is done!!:) but I dunno how to implement?:(

```
[{'body': {'markdown': u'http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/gextracto/userdata/', 'html': u'http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/gextracto/userdata/\r<br/>'}, u'To': u'infowikitech@gmail.com', u'From': u'Gextracto <infowikkitech@gmail.com>', 'id': u'151202ad347314bc', u'Subject': u'Your Download Ready!'}]
```

but it is coming in this format-

```
[<UserData: UserData object>, <UserData: UserData object>, <UserData: UserData object>, <UserData: UserData object>, <UserData: UserData object>, <UserData: UserData object>, <UserData: UserData object>, <UserData: UserData object>, <UserData: UserData object>, <UserData: UserData object>, <UserData: UserData object>, <UserData: UserData object>, <UserData: UserData object>]
```

this is where i am retrieving the data-

```
def get(self,request, format=None):
        label_id = request.GET['label']
        all_mails=UserData.objects.filter(label=label_id)
        return Response(all_mails)
```

This is where i am writing is to .json-

```
function bulk_download_json(label_id){

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"/initiate_download/?label="+label_id,
        success:function(data){
            bulk_mails=data;

            bulk_download_filename = label_id.concat(".json");

            var bulk_json_file = "text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(bulk_mails));
            $('<a id="bulk_json_link" href="data:' + bulk_json_file + '" download="'+bulk_download_filename+'">download JSON</a>').appendTo('#bulk_json_content');
            document.getElementById('bulk_json_link').click();  
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the data into a json here.

Run this query first,which will display the data into the known format.

```
data = your_db.objects.all().values()
```

After this is done, you may use,

```
import json
data_json = json.loads(dumps(data))
```

Also this link may help you more.('[django serialize queryset.values() into json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650448/django-serialize-queryset-values-into-json)')

Comment: Thanks I am glad that it works .Please accept the answer then :-)

Comment: @RahulLakhanpal, Why would the op accept the poorest answer?

Comment: Considering the fact that he hasn't used serializers, my solution provides a quick way out to get things working. However I did post the link which would have helped him more.