# Django: "Object of type 'QuerySet' is not JSON serializable"

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following data which I want to pass to JsonResponse.

```
coin_amount = [Portfolio.objects.filter(user = request.user, coin = key['coin']).values('amount') for key in coin_sell_options]

print(list(coin_amount))
```

However this returns a [ValuesQuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values), which is not Json serializable:

```
[<QuerySet [{'amount': Decimal('3.0000000')}]>, <QuerySet [{'amount': 
Decimal('0.1000000')}]>, <QuerySet [{'amount': Decimal('9.0000000')}]>]
```

That's problematic because I need a list that is JSON serializable.

So I need to get a list like this from my ValuesQuerySet somehow:

```
['3.0000000', '0.1000000', '9.0000000']
```

Comment: You should either use Django's built-in serializers, or (preferably) the Django REST Framework.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still learning Django and am not familiar with either. Will look these up.

Comment: I'm struggling with this, every answer I've tried on similar questions such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/31994176/3219210 still throws up the same error. Please could elaborate a bit further?

Comment: As apparent from your output, add ["amount"] like
coin_amount = [Portfolio.objects.filter(user = request.user, coin = key['coin']).values('amount')["amount"] for key in coin_sell_options]

This will however give you a list of list.

Comment: To flatten use


coin_amount = [item for sublist in coin_amount for item in sublist]

Comment: Adding ["amount"] like that results in TypeError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
coin_amount = [Portfolio.objects.filter(user=request.user, coin=key['coin']).values('amount') for key in coin_sell_options]
```

does NOT "returns a ValuesQuerySet", it returns a `list` of `ValuesQuerySet`. What you want is the `__in` lookup operator:

```
coins = [key['coin'] for key in coin_sell_options]
coin_amount = list(Portfolio.objects.filter(user=request.user, coin__in=coins).values_list('amount', flat=True))
coin_amount = [str(x) for x in coin_amount]

print(coin_amount)
```