# How to serialize a ValuesQuerySet using django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'd like to build an API for a complex query.

Having read the documentation, I prefer using django-rest-framework, which will provide serialization and pagination automatically for a ValuesQuerySet, rather than doing my own serialization.

However, I only found docs for default model QuerySet and did not find any documentation for serializing ValuesQuerySet (when the model is not known). How can I do that?

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601174/converting-a-django-valuesqueryset-to-a-json-object) but the solution was not applicable in my case.

Here is the code, NOT using django-rest-framework:

```
@login_required
def category_tallies(request):
    my_friends = FacebookUser.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
    cat_tallies = FacebookLike.objects.filter(id__in=my_friends).values('category').annotate(Count('category')).order_by('-category__count')
    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(cat_tallies),
        mimetype='application/json')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from django.core import serializers

cat_tallies = FacebookLike.objects.filter(id__in=my_friends).annotate(count=Count('category')).order_by('-count')
json_dump = serializers.serialize('json', cat_tallies, fields=('category','count'))
```

Comment: Can serializers.serialize do pagination?

Comment: All paginator needs is an iterable. So, yes you can