# Get JavaScript array from Django view

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, django

I am using Django with the Google Charts API.  I need to construct a JavaScript array to render a bar chart showing the # of objects created in a given day.

The ***expected*** array printed to the template should look like:

```
  ...

  function drawStuff() {
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Date', '# of records'],
      ['2015-03-07', 3],    // Expected format:  ['Date', # of objects]
      ['2015-03-08', 8],
    ]);

  ...
```

**views.py**:

```
class LogsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'logs.html'


    def ValuesQuerySetToDict(self, vqs):
        return [ [item['date_created'], item['created_count'] ] for item in vqs]

    def render_chart_data(self, **kwargs):
        queryset = LogEntry.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).extra(
            {'date_created': 'date(created)'}
            ).values('date_created').annotate(created_count=Count('id'))
        modified_dict = self.ValuesQuerySetToDict(queryset)

        return json.dumps(modified_dict)


     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(
            LogsView, self
        ).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['chart_data'] = self.render_chart_data()
```

The following is rendered to my django template (I bypassed sending it to JavaScript for now to see what was returned...

[image: weird formatted data]

When I believe I need to return a JavaScript array like the following:

```
["2015-02-18", 3],
["2015-02-19", 12],
["2015-02-21", 1],
```

And feed that to the drawStuff function which will render the barchart.

**Alternate Method**

I followed the [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601174/converting-a-django-valuesqueryset-to-a-json-object) on StackOverflow and modified the render_chart_data to use django serializer [like this](https://gist.github.com/joefusaro/4b6b400e45941e80220e) but I am getting an error: " 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: Are you sure that `queryset`, `converted` or `json_data` contains your expected values?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer - I updated and now confirm that the queryset data is being returned via the Django view.

Comment: How about `modified_dict`? Can you update your post with the values so that we can all check if `json.dumps` is actually provided correct values?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer - Sorry for the confusion, here is all of the relevant views.py code: https://gist.github.com/joefusaro/4b6b400e45941e80220e

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer - thank you for trying to help on this, I was able to work through the issue and now have the bar chart data rendered to the javascript & HTML.  Any feedback you have on my solution would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all who offered assistance on this.

Two things needed to changed; the ValuesQuerySetToDict function needed to be rewritten as follows:

```
def ValuesQuerySetToDict(self, vqs):
    list_vals = [ ['Date', '# of records'] ]
    for item in vqs:
        list_vals.append(
            # convert datetime object to string otherwise JSON serialization error
            [ str(item['date_created']), item['created_count'] ]
            )

    return list_vals
```

And the render_chart_data function needed to be rewritten as follows:

```
def render_chart_data(self, **kwargs):
    queryset = LogEntry.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).extra(
        {'date_created': 'date(created)'}
        ).values('date_created').annotate(created_count=Count('id')).order_by('created-date')
    modified_list = list(self.ValuesQuerySetToDict(queryset))
    json_data = json.dumps(modified_list)

    return json_data
```

Finally, {{ chart_data }} needed to be passed to to the drawStuff function, like so:

```
  function drawStuff() {
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
        {{ chart_data|safe }}
        );
```

I've posted views.py and logs.html [here](https://gist.github.com/joefusaro/4b6b400e45941e80220e).

Answer (score -1):

1. In your queryset, render **created_count as string** and not as integer. Json's do not behave well with Integers.
2. In your JS function **drawStuff**, chart_data should be parsed as json. See below:

```
 var json_string = '{{chart_data}}';
 var json = JSON.parse(json_string);
 var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(json)
```